# ESmodules: The requested module '****' does not provide an export named '****'

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, commonjs, esmodules

Newbie question here. I have this problem using ESmodules.

SyntaxError: The requested module './esModules.js' does not provide an export named 'add'.

I do have the "Type": "modules" in my package.json

My code:

// index.js

```
import add from "./esModules.js";

let num1 = 15;
let num2 = 20;

console.log(add(num1, num2));
```

// esModules.js

```
export const add = (num1, num2) => {
  result = num1 + num2;
};
```

I tried adding "export default add;" which I read somewhere,

I tried using { add } in the import sentence,

I tried without ".js" in the import sentence,

but it doesn´t work either.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Solution: It worked with { add } and adding the "return result" in the add function!

Comment: `I tried using { add } in the import sentence` - that should work - what may be an issue is that `result` is not declared ... but then, you'd get a different error

Comment: Hi @JaromandaX, the problem was that the "return" in the add function was missing! Weird thing... haha

Answer (score 0):

There could be 2 ways to fix this problem out, first make the export default, or add {} while importing it. Make sure to return the result in both the cases, for assistance
**Case 1:**

`index.js`

```js
import add from "./esModules.js";

let num1 = 15;
let num2 = 20;

console.log(add(num1, num2));
```

`esModules.js`

```js
export const add = (num1, num2) => {
  result = num1 + num2;
  return result;
};
```

**Case 1:**

`index.js`

```js
import add from "./esModules.js";

let num1 = 15;
let num2 = 20;

console.log(add(num1, num2));
```

`esModules.js`

```js
const add = (num1, num2) => {
  result = num1 + num2;
  return result;
};
export default add;
```